# iOS8 iTunes Connect and Testflight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios8, testflight

As I understand in order to invite user to be internal tester you need to add them to iTunes connect. 
So far so good.

My issue is that my iCloud account is already link to another iTunes Connect account ( which I use to publish and manage personal app ) but I also would like to be able to test my company app which is obviously on a different iTunes connect account and I use a different Apple ID to acces it.

The iOS8 testflight app doesn't allow you to switch account.

Do I have to change my iCloud account on my phone in order to access my company internal beta version.

Any body have a better idea?

Comment: I have similar issue. Tried deleting the app and unsynch iCloud, but still no way. But @Abhinit's tips work. If we change the AppStore credential, then TestFlight use that apple ID. Better than changing the iCloud account which mess up all syncing!

Comment: Is there somewhere we can harass Apple to allow multiple Itunes Connect accounts per Apple ID like they do for Developer Center?

Comment: This is annoying, I know. The same issue stops Devs with personal accounts from managing parts of the ITC process unless signed in as the Agent...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've send the invite to my company account but open it on my iPhone link to my personal iCloud Account and it just open Testflight and it work.

Edit 01-10-2014
It seem like this trick doesn't work anymore. Testflight app is now saying that "this tester does not have access to this app"

Comment: I also figured out that to change the Apple ID in the testflight app, all you have to do is to login with whatever ID you want in the AppStore app.

Comment: This just worked for me :) After your edit saying it stopped working.

Comment: @Jake were you using an internal or external beta?

Comment: I'm an internal tester

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I've dealt with this situation.

If you have a user that you would like to be an internal tester in your organization (or the converse -- perhaps you have a client who has their own iTunes Connect account and *you* need access to their account as a tester or admin or developer) and they have a Gmail account, you can do the "+foo" trick on their email address, which Gmail allows through to their email, and iTunes Connect thinks it's a different iTunes Connect account.

For example, if the person I want to add is "fred@myclient.com", I would send him an invitation as "fred+appname@myclient.com", and their Gmail-based mail system will let the email through just fine.

Then, they create a new, separate Apple ID with "fred+appname@myclient.com", and iTunes doesn't complain.

Then when they receive the follow-up notification to join TestFlight, it arrives at the right email address, and when they tap the button in the email it opens TestFlight on their device, they sign in with their normal Apple ID (even if it's fredjones@gmail.com), and then they're in.

It feels a little hackish, but it works.

Because I'm dealing with this situation again with a client, I wrote up the following blog post:

http://interactivelogic.net/wp/2016/01/how-to-add-an-internal-tester-to-testflight-if-they-already-have-an-itunes-connect-account/

Hope this helps future visitors!